# cmd/ batch command to make windows FULL FULL SCREEN

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, fullscreen

I'm just wondering if there is a cmd/batch command out there to make a file full screen.  I'm not just talking about maximized I'm talking about like full screen like when you are playing a game. I know that /max makes the program maximized not FULL screen.  If you do not know what I mean just hit `F11` on windows. Thanks!

Comment: Which Windows are you in? There's no fullscreen in cmd.exe for Vista through 8.1. It's only introduced back in Windows 10

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, the CMD shell doesn't implement this. It's a feature of the console/terminal application that provides the window and standard I/O files. By default this is an instance of the console host process, conhost.exe (Windows 7+) in cooperation with the console device driver, condrv.sys (Windows 8+).

Comment: @ErykSun I know about conhost.exe. But the OP probably wanted to make *another window* fullscreen not the console window. Beside F11 is not what's commonly used to make conhost fullscreen because it has always been Alt+Enter since decades ago

Answer (score 1):

Make a shortcut to your batch file and the go to properties for the shortcut. Then somewhere in the properties window there will be a option for screen resolution in the display tab. Just up the resolution to the height and width you need.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD windows and write the following code:

```
mode 800
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you'll need [windowmode.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) and [getCMDPid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat):

```
call getcmdbit.bat
call windowmode.bat -pid %errorlevel% -mode maximized
```

Comment: Maximized is not full screen. The console dropped support for full-screen mode in Vista, but the new console in Windows 10 brought it back. The hotkey toggle is Alt+Enter (or F11, but not in WSL). There's no API for it anymore, so you would need a little app to send this keyboard input to the console window.

Comment: @eryksun - hmm.. At the moment I can come with anything better. I'm failing to send alt+enter with the common send keys libraries - I'll need to check if it is possible to use p/invoke about that...

Comment: Rather than using `SendInput`, it'll be more reliable to `PostMessage` the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYUP` messages for `VK_MENU` and `VK_RETURN` directly to the console window (from `GetConsoleWindow`). Also, to be more than a command that toggles full-screen mode, it needs to be able to query the current window state. A full-screen window should be top-most, checked via `GetWindowInfo`, and the rect from `GetWindowRect` should be the screen rect from `MonitorFromWindow` and `GetMonitorInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, cmd not allowing that